# How to typify a nested object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to typify a nested object?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKh8S.png)

***Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ UA: {}; RU: {}; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ UA: {}; RU: {}; }'.  TS7053***

```
interface IState {
  showInfo: any,
  priceVariantIndex: any,
  loaded: any,
  imgLoaded: any,
  imgUrl: any,
  selectedCutlery: any,
  product: any,
}

  state = {
    showInfo: false,
    priceVariantIndex: 0,
    loaded: false,
    imgLoaded: false,
    imgUrl: '',
    selectedCutlery: '',
    product: {
      productTranslations: {
        UA: {},
        RU: {}
      }
    }
  }

      <Link to={linkObject}>
        {this.props.language &&
        this.state.product.productTranslations[`${this.props.language}`]
          .name != undefined
          ? this.state.product.productTranslations[
              `${this.props.language}` // err
            ].name
          : product.name}
      </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

The conflict here is between the type of `language` in `props`, which is a `string` and the type of `productTranslations` which is type `{ UA: {}, RU: {} }`.

If you don't want to explicitly type of `language` to the specific letter-codes that you are using to represent languages, you can update your `product` type in the `IState` interface to

`product: { productTranslations: { [language: string]: any } };`

Which now says that `this.state.product` has a `productTranslations` property which is a mapping of `string` to `any`.

As an aside, I'd highly recommend eliminating all of those `any` types, or at least change them to `unknown` so that you don't run into issues that TypeScript could definitely have caught for you.

Comment: Code: https://i.imgur.com/dj1Jxdc.png
Error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ UA: {}; RU: {}; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ UA: {}; RU: {}; }'.  TS7053`